# Is there any way to prevent share, fork option in Stackblitz

Tags: javascript, angular, api, sdk, stackblitz

I need to embed Stackblitz on my site. The user can edit the document and render the output on the screen. I used Stackblitz api to embed the iframe. I cant find any document on Stackblitz.io to hide those options (share code). Can anyone help me ?

[image]

Comment: I'm trying programming test like feature. It's not good to allow this. And also, I don't want the student to navigate out of the page .

Comment: I understand what you saying. I asked because, I want to prevent the easy way to share code. So there is no way to do that ?

Comment: I used their SDK to provide the iframe. my sample code https://sdk-create-project-4pnxpm.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project you need to add `forceEmbedLayout: true`

```
window['embedNewProject'] = () => {
  sdk.embedProject('myDiv', project, { height: 320, **forceEmbedLayout: true** });
}
```